# How to prevent access to websites built in certain regions on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, networking, firewall, restrictions

I would like to prevent the computer from visiting any website that is set in China. The operating system is Windows 10. I have already got a .csv file containing all IP's in China, in which each row is arranged in the format like `1.0.1.0, 1.0.3.255 \n` denoting IP's from `1.0.1.0` to `1.0.3.255`. So is it possible to accomplish such goal and how to do so?

There are too many entries (hundreds of thousands) to manually add into the outbound rules of the firewall. While redirecting to 127.0.0.1 in the `hosts` file seems to work for only URL's, not for IP's (is this true?).

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possibility that I found, which is today only available
from the internet archive.
I have not tested it, but here is how to use it.

- Start a PowerShell session as Administrator and run the command
  `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` and exit the session
  (you may undo this later on)
- Download the zip file
  [windows_firewall_script.zip](https://web.archive.org/web/20131008171531/http://mixoftech.com/downloads/windows_firewall_script.zip)
  and unpack it into a folder
- You will find in it the file `BlockList.txt` which starts with
  `# China` (`#` denotes a comment line)
- Find the line `# Russia` and delete everything from this line and
  to the end of the file
- Append to the file any missing IPs in the same CIDR format and save
- Right-click on the file `Import-Firewall-Blocklist.ps1` and select
  "Run with PowerShell"

This script will create inbound and outbound rules in the
Windows Firewall to block all the IPv4 and/or IPv6 addresses listed
in the file `BlockList.txt`.

In the case the this PowerShell script will itself disappear
in the future, here is a copy:

```
####################################################################################
#.Synopsis 
#    Block all IP addresses listed in a text file using the Windows Firewall.
#
#.Description 
#    Script will create inbound and outbound rules in the Windows Firewall to
#    block all the IPv4 and/or IPv6 addresses listed in an input text file.  IP
#    address ranges can be defined with CIDR notation (10.4.0.0/16) or with a
#    dash (10.4.0.0-10.4.255.255).  Comments and blank lines are ignored in the
#    input file.  The script deletes and recreates the rules each time the 
#    script is run, so don't edit the rules by hand.  Requires admin privileges.
#    Multiple rules will be created if the input list is large.  Requires
#    Windows Vista, Windows 7, Server 2008 or later operating system.  Blocking
#    thousands of ranges does not seem to impede performance, but will slow
#    the loading of the Windows Firewall snap-in and lengthen the time it takes
#    to disable/enable a network interface. This script is just a wrapper for
#    the netsh.exe tool.  You can block individual IP addresses too, you do not
#    need to use CIDR notation for this (10.1.1.1/32) though it does work.
#
#.Parameter InputFile
#    File containing IP addresses and ranges to block; IPv4 and IPv6 supported.
#    By default, the script will look for and use a file named 'blocklist.txt'.
#
#.Parameter RuleName
#    (Optional) Override default firewall rule name; default based on file name.
#    When used with -DeleteOnly, just give the rule basename without the "-#1".
#
#.Parameter ProfileType
#    (Optional) Comma-delimited list of network profile types for which the
#    blocking rules will apply: public, private, domain, any (default = any).
#
#.Parameter InterfaceType
#    (Optional) Comma-delimited list of interface types for which the
#    blocking rules will apply: wireless, ras, lan, any (default = any).
#
#.Parameter DeleteOnly
#    (Switch) Matching firewall rules will be deleted, none will be created.
#    When used with -RuleName, leave off the "-#1" at the end of the rulename.
#
#.Example 
#    import-firewall-blocklist.ps1 -inputfile IpToBlock.txt
#
#.Example
#    import-firewall-blocklist.ps1 -inputfile iptoblock.txt -profiletype public
#
#.Example
#    import-firewall-blocklist.ps1 -inputfile iptoblock.txt -interfacetype wireless
#
#.Example 
#    import-firewall-blocklist.ps1 -inputfile IpToBlock.txt -deleteonly
#
#.Example 
#    import-firewall-blocklist.ps1 -rulename IpToBlock -deleteonly
#
#Requires -Version 1.0 
#
#.Notes 
#  Author: Jason Fossen (http://www.sans.org/windows-security/)  
# Version: 1.3
# Updated: 31.Mar.2012
#   LEGAL: PUBLIC DOMAIN.  SCRIPT PROVIDED "AS IS" WITH NO WARRANTIES OR GUARANTEES OF 
#          ANY KIND, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO MERCHANTABILITY AND/OR FITNESS FOR
#          A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  ALL RISKS OF DAMAGE REMAINS WITH THE USER, EVEN IF
#          THE AUTHOR, SUPPLIER OR DISTRIBUTOR HAS BEEN ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF
#          ANY SUCH DAMAGE.  IF YOUR STATE DOES NOT PERMIT THE COMPLETE LIMITATION OF
#          LIABILITY, THEN DELETE THIS FILE SINCE YOU ARE NOW PROHIBITED TO HAVE IT.
####################################################################################
    
param ($InputFile = "BlockList.txt", $RuleName, $ProfileType = "any", $InterfaceType = "any", [Switch] $DeleteOnly)

# Look for some help arguments, show help, then quit.
if ($InputFile -match '/[?h]') { "`nPlease run 'get-help .\import-firewall-blocklist.ps1 -full' for help on PowerShell 2.0 and later, or just read the script's header in a text editor.`n" ; exit }  

# Get input file and set the name of the firewall rule.
$file = get-item $InputFile -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue # Sometimes rules will be deleted by name and there is no file.
if (-not $? -and -not $DeleteOnly) { "`nCannot find $InputFile, quitting...`n" ; exit } 
if (-not $rulename) { $rulename = $file.basename }  # The '-#1' will be appended later.

# Description will be seen in the properties of the firewall rules.
$description = "Rule created by script. Do not edit rule by hand, it will be overwritten when the script is run again. By default, the name of the rule is named after the input file."

# Any existing firewall rules which match the name are deleted every time the script runs.
"`nDeleting any inbound or outbound firewall rules named like '$rulename-#*'`n"
$currentrules = netsh.exe advfirewall firewall show rule name=all | select-string '^[Rule Name|Regelname|Nome]+:\s+(.+$)' | foreach { $_.matches[0].groups[1].value } 
if ($currentrules.count -lt 3) {"`nProblem getting a list of current firewall rules, quitting...`n" ; exit } 
# Note: If you are getting the above error, try editing the regex pattern two lines above to include the 'Rule Name' in your local language.
$currentrules | foreach { if ($_ -like "$rulename-#*"){ netsh.exe advfirewall firewall delete rule name="$_" | out-null } } 

# Don't create the firewall rules again if the -DeleteOnly switch was used.
if ($deleteonly -and $rulename) { "`nReminder: when deleting by name, leave off the '-#1' at the end of the rulename.`n" } 
if ($deleteonly) { exit } 

# Create array of IP ranges; any line that doesn't start like an IPv4/IPv6 address is ignored.
$ranges = get-content $file | where {($_.trim().length -ne 0) -and ($_ -match '^[0-9a-f]{1,4}[\.\:]')} 
if (-not $?) { "`nCould not parse $file, quitting...`n" ; exit } 
$linecount = $ranges.count
if ($linecount -eq 0) { "`nZero IP addresses to block, quitting...`n" ; exit } 

# Now start creating rules with hundreds of IP address ranges per rule.  Testing shows
# that netsh.exe errors begin to occur with more than 400 IPv4 ranges per rule, and 
# this number might still be too large when using IPv6 or the Start-End format, so 
# default to only 200 ranges per rule, but feel free to edit the following variable:
$MaxRangesPerRule = 200

$i = 1                    # Rule number counter, when more than one rule must be created, e.g., BlockList-#001.
$start = 1                # For array slicing out of IP $ranges.
$end = $maxrangesperrule  # For array slicing out of IP $ranges.
do {
    $icount = $i.tostring().padleft(3,"0")  # Used in name of rule, e.g., BlockList-#042.
    
    if ($end -gt $linecount) { $end = $linecount } 
    $textranges = [System.String]::Join(",",$($ranges[$($start - 1)..$($end - 1)])) 

    "`nCreating an inbound firewall rule named '$rulename-#$icount' for IP ranges $start - $end" 
    netsh.exe advfirewall firewall add rule name="$rulename-#$icount" dir=in action=block localip=any remoteip="$textranges" description="$description" profile="$profiletype" interfacetype="$interfacetype"
    if (-not $?) { "`nFailed to create '$rulename-#$icount' inbound rule for some reason, continuing anyway..."}
    
    "`nCreating an outbound firewall rule named '$rulename-#$icount' for IP ranges $start - $end" 
    netsh.exe advfirewall firewall add rule name="$rulename-#$icount" dir=out action=block localip=any remoteip="$textranges" description="$description" profile="$profiletype" interfacetype="$interfacetype"
    if (-not $?) { "`nFailed to create '$rulename-#$icount' outbound rule for some reason, continuing anyway..."}
    
    $i++
    $start += $maxrangesperrule
    $end += $maxrangesperrule
} while ($start -le $linecount)

# END-O-SCRIPT
```

Comment: Thank you very much and I will try this resolution.